# How do I clear Callback stack

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, lifecycle

Main_thread starts an Activity-A which has a method called Callback. Main also starts a service that runs and sends a Broadcast and execution goes to Callback in Activity-A; however Activity-A had also called Activity-B which was executing when the event occurred. How does Activity-A get Activity-B off the Callback stack?

Comment: Is this an Android question?

Comment: Yes Android Kotlin

Comment: It’s unclear what your last sentence means. By “get off” do you mean you want to *get a reference* to ActivityB, or that you want to *remove* it from the Android task stack? What do you mean by the term “callback stack”, exactly?

Comment: I mean, as if I never called it…. One way BroadcastReceiver to Activity-B telling it to finish itself, or finish() B from onStop() in B when the callback takes it to A. Cleaner way?